# How to save custom rule in ufw? Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, port, ufw

I am using ufw and I would like to add a custom rule

> iptables -I INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

But even following

> iptable-save

Upon reboot, the rule is gone.

I also cannot figure out how to enable connection tracking in ufw

How do I get ufw to remember my rule at reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the rule to  `/etc/ufw/before.rules` or `/etc/ufw/after.rules`

According to the man page

ufw  is  in  part  a  front-end  for   iptables-restore,  with   its   rules   saved  in /etc/ufw/before.rules,  /etc/ufw/after.rules  and  /etc/ufw/user.rules

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ufw-framework.8.html

---

Another approach
Create a custom rule in

```
sudo nano /etc/ufw/custom.rules
```

Add your custom rule to the file

```
-I INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Add the following in /etc/ufw/after.rules

```
*filter
# your existing rules...
# your existing rules...

# Include the custom rules file
-A ufw-user-input -f /etc/ufw/custom.rules

COMMIT
```

Reboot to test.

Comment: I just added the rule in incorrectly apparently. I added the rule -I INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT to line 1 (after line 10 failed) in before.rules and now that server won't boot. I am reinstalling it right now. From the beginning. Any hints on how to add it correctly? For once I get back there.

Comment: You could change it to ufw format `sudo ufw allow from any to any state RELATED,ESTABLISHED`

Comment: I get ERROR: Invalid token 'state'. I tried ctstate also. same token error.

Comment: Also, if I add the iptables syntax to my before.rules, upon ufw reload, the port acts and responds as should be. But upon reboot, it does not work anymore and the rule appears in the proper place. If I issue a ufw reload command, the rule will begin functioning correctly

Comment: Sounds like you didn't enabled systemd service for ufw. `systemctl enable ufw`

Comment: That got me closer but I am still not on top of f2b-ufw. Which is where I need to be for my rule to function.

Comment: I added another approach

Comment: And is the conntrack module enabled `sudo lsmod | grep conntrack`